# NextJS store parameters in URL to be used in fetch request in components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a NextJS app that works as an embeddable widget using iframes. The app depends on URL parameters being present to perform fetch requests to the API within the RSC's. The only way I know to get search params is either in client components, or as the searchParams prop in RSC's. Id prefer to have some type of wrapper/provider handle storing these query params rather than writing logic in every single page. My thought is anytime the query parameters are detected in the URL, a client component stores them and then performs a redirect so that they are available on the next request. Does this seem like the only option? Below is my implementation however when rendered, the API is using the values from the previous request. If I refresh, then it uses the parameters presented in the URL.

Client Component

```
'use client';

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { defaultSession } from '../lib/session';

export function SessionProvider({ children }) {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [session, setSession] = useState(defaultSession);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const perscomId = searchParams.get('perscomid');
  const apiKey = searchParams.get('apikey');

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('perscomId', perscomId);
  formData.append('apiKey', apiKey);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (apiKey) {
      fetch('/api/session', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        cache: 'no-store'
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((session) => {
          setSession(session);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }
  }, [apiKey, perscomId]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Route:

```
import { getIronSession } from 'iron-session';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { defaultSession, sessionOptions } from '../../../lib/session';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export async function POST(request) {
  const session = await getIronSession(cookies(), sessionOptions);
  const formData = await request.formData();

  session.isLoggedIn = true;
  session.perscomId = formData.get('perscomId') ?? '';
  session.apiKey = formData.get('apiKey') ?? '';

  await session.save();

  return Response.redirect(request.nextUrl.origin, 303);
}

export async function GET(request) {
  const session = await getIronSession(cookies(), sessionOptions);
  const action = new URL(request.url).searchParams.get('action');

  if (action === 'logout') {
    session.destroy();

    return redirect('/');
  }

  if (session.isLoggedIn !== true) {
    return Response.json(defaultSession);
  }

  return Response.json(session);
}
```